# Haskell function incompatible type and definition

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand this function (taken from [here](https://lhbg-book.link/03-html/06-escaping_characters.html))

```
escape :: String -> String
escape =
  let
    escapeChar c =
      case c of
        '<' -> "&lt;"
        '>' -> "&gt;"
        _ -> [c]
  in
    concat . map escapeChar
```

My questions are:

1. According to the type, `escape` is a function that takes a `String`. But it seems that in in the fuction definition it does not receive any argument. How does this work?
2. What is the relationship between `escapeChar` and `c`? How is that relationship established? Does `c` coming right after `escapeChar` have a meaning?

Comment: The key term here is "point-free style".

Comment: The value of `concat . map escapeChar` is itself a function of type `String -> String`, so that is assigned to `escape`. `escape x = ...` is just another way of writing `escape = \x -> ...` (ignoring some subtle differences between the two).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would it be easier if `escapeChar` were a top-level definition using pattern matching:

```
escape :: String -> String
escape = concatMap escapeChar

escapeChar :: Char -> String
escapeChar '<' = "&lt;"
escapeChar '>' = "&gt;"
escapeChar ch  = [ch]
```

`[ch]` is a singleton list, it turns `ch :: Char` into a `[ch] :: String`.

In Haskell you can remove/add an argument from/to each side ([*eta conversion*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion)). `escape` is the *eta reduced* form of

```
escape :: String -> String
escape str = concatMap escapeChar str
```

Just like, if you wanted to define a synonym for `(+)` you have equivalent ways of writing it. I feel like the `add = (+)` is clearest, you are identifying the two functions. The arguments are the same on both sides so we don't specify them.

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add     = (+)
add a   = (+) a
add a   = (a +)
add a b = (+) a b
add a b = a + b
```

These are equivalent ways of writing `escape`:

```
escape = concat . map escapeChar
```

```
escape str = concat (map escapeChar str)
```

Answer (score 4):

> According to the type, escape is a function that takes a String. But it seems that in in the fuction definition it does not receive any argument. How does this work?

`concat . map escape` returns a *function*. That function will take a string and process it.

> What is the relationship between `escapeChar` and `c`? How is that relationship established? Does `c` coming right after `escapeChar` have a meaning?

Yes, it is the first (and only) parameter of the function. It is a `Char`acter, and the `escapeChar` function maps that `Char` on a `String`. The `let` clause thus defines a function `escapeChar :: Char -> String` that will then be used in `concat . map escape` (or perhaps better `concatMap escape`). This will map each `Char` of the given `String` to a substring, and these are then concatenated together as a result.

Answer (score 3):

the `map` function has a signature `(a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])` this means that the map function takes in a function(the escapeChar function) and returns a function that converts a list using that function(the escapeChar function). `map escapeChar` returns a function that converts a string using the escapeChar function on each character in the string.